# Generic type data vs Specific Bean in Drools?

Tags: java, drools

We are creating a generic bean for the data coming from database adding a name property to differentiate and use map to hold data from SQL.

```
Class Data{
private string name;
private Mao<String,Object> row;
//getters/setters
}
```

My question is performance wise which option is Better creating different bean for each type of data ?

Answer (score 0):

A fact's class is nothing but another property to the rules engine. If you have different class names, it creates tuples collecting objects of a class.

If you have one Data class, you still have the tuple with all objects, and then the name property splits the big tuple into smaller tuples.

I guess you can answer your question yourself.

Comment: Hi Laune thanks for the answer. How does these two affect indexing ?

Comment: Which "indexing"?